# Conditional Lambda Foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that I am iterating through as follows.

```
foreach (Statistics value in data.Where(x => x.DateOrTime >= start[0]))
```

However, I want to add a check if myVariable == 0 then do it the way above.  Else do it as follows.

```
foreach (Statistics value in data)
```

So basically, I want to do an if/else within the expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
foreach (Statistics value in data.Where(x => myVariable != 0 || 
                                             x.DateOrTime >= start[0]))
```

Alternatively:

```
var query = myVariable == 0 ? data.Where(x => x.DateOrTime >= start[0]) : data;
foreach (Statistics value in query)
{
}
```

Comment: Currently reading that and haven't gotten that far in it.  Thank you!